# Property access of object within an array using a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access a property of an object which is within an object in an array. Quite the mouthful. The catch is that I want to do this using a variable. Its probably easier if i explain with code;

```
var array= [
  { id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" }},
  { id: 1, client: { id:1, clientName: "Tom" }}
]
console.log(array[0][client][clientName]); // Displays correctly
```

So the above code works as expected using the brackets notation. But as I said earlier I need to use a Variable like this example;

```
var array= [
  { id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" }},
  { id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" }}
]
var property = "client.clientName";
console.log(array[0][property]); // Does not work
```

I understand why this code wouldn't work but really this is more of a pseudo code to explain what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: or use something like https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you can't get it like that way instead split and get nested properties. Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to get the nested property by splitting the property string using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```
// split the string and iterate over the result array
property.split('.').reduce(function(o, p) {
  // check object defined and return nested property value
  return o && o[p];
  // set initial value as the object where you need to fetch data
}, array[0])
```

```js
var array = [{
  id: 0,
  client: {
    id: 0,
    clientName: "John"
  }
}, {
  id: 0,
  client: {
    id: 0,
    clientName: "John"
  }
}]

var property = "client.clientName";
console.log(
  property.split('.').reduce(function(o, p) {
    return o && o[p];
  }, array[0])
);
```

Comment: Hey! Pretty good one, storing it for later :D

Comment: Hey bro, this is just what I needed thank you!

Comment: @OliverFurmage : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array= [
  { id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" }},
  { id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" }}
]
var property = "client.clientName",
    getPropByString=function(data,val){
      val=val.split(/\./g);
      var dataApp=data;
      val.forEach(function(prop){
        dataApp=dataApp[prop];
      });
      return dataApp;
    };
console.log(getPropByString(array[0],property));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function, which splits the string with the property names and reduce the given object.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var array = [{ id: 0, client: { id:0, clientName: "John" } }, { id: 1, client: { id:1, clientName: "Tom" } }],
    property = "client.clientName";

console.log(getValue(array[0], property));
```

Comment: From the question: *The catch is that I want to do this using a variable* — You're not using the variable and are hardcoding the values into the source code.

Comment: @Quentin, oh, i missed that.